# How to remove "generated by LaTeXML" message?

Tags: latexml

I used LaTeXML (version 0.8.5) as a part of generating an ebook, as follows:

```
latexml --dest ../book.xml main.tex
```

It leaves a message at the end of the book:

[image: generated message]

How do I remove this message?

Comment: The relevant issue from that project: https://github.com/brucemiller/LaTeXML/issues/1105

Answer (score 1):

I'll first say that line looks like a citation/logo, so removing it seems to be deceptive, if it's not explicitly forbidden (for example, Google Maps explicitly does not allow you to hide their logo).

But if you want to do this anyway, there's two approaches.  The easier is to use css to hide it with: `footer.ltx_page_footer { display: none; }`.  This technically hides the message, not removes it.

If you really want to remove it, you can supply a custom xslt that extends the xslt that you're using for `latexmlpost`.

Comment: Point taken. I might leave it. I can't find anything about whether attribution is required. I'd be happy to acknowledge them, but putting it inside the artifact does mess with how it looks, so I feel controlling that is not crazy.

Comment: Coming back to this a month later, if you have a simple document where that footer is messing up the layout in an ebook, I'm fairly sure they'd be interested in making that work.

Comment: LaTeXML is public domain and explicitly revokes its own copyright claim. (See [here](https://math.nist.gov/~BMiller/LaTeXML/notices.html).) I cannot see how there could be any way it can "forbid" you from doing anything you like with it.